# Footer coming on top while exporting radgrid inside a radgrid

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a radgrid inside radgrid. While exporting to excel or word the footer is coming on top of the data row ie first the footer is coming and then the row. 
Please help me in this. below is the code snippet.

```
                BorderStyle="None"
                PageSize="50"                        
                AllowPaging="true"
                 ShowFooter="false"
                OnNeedDataSource="rgMonthlyBalancingPools_OnNeedDataSource"
                OnPdfExporting="rgMonthlyBalancingPools_PdfExporting"
                OnGridExporting="rgMonthlyBalancingPools_GridExporting"


                runat="server">

    <ExportSettings FileName="NonFirmMonthlyBalancingPools" 
                    OpenInNewWindow="true" ExportOnlyData="false" 
                    >
        <Csv ColumnDelimiter="Comma" RowDelimiter="NewLine" FileExtension="csv" />
        <Pdf PageWidth="350mm" PageHeight="210mm" />
    </ExportSettings>

<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="true" >

    <ItemTemplate>

        <div>

            <h3>Pool Summary</h3>
            <telerik:RadGrid    ID="rgPoolSummary" 
                                AllowSorting="true"
                                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                ShowFooter="true"                                    
                                AllowPaging="false"
                                CssClass="AutoShrink"
                                EnableNoRecordsTemplate="True"
                                OnItemCommand="rg_ItemCommand"
                                OnNeedDataSource="rgPoolSummary_OnNeedDataSource"
                                runat="server">
                <ExportSettings FileName="NonFirmMonthlyBalancingPoolSummary" 
                                OpenInNewWindow="true"  ExportOnlyData="true" IgnorePaging="true">
                    <Csv ColumnDelimiter="Comma" RowDelimiter="NewLine" FileExtension="csv" />
                </ExportSettings>
                <MasterTableView CssClass="AutoShrink" CommandItemDisplay="Top" GridLines="Both" BorderStyle="Solid">
                    <Columns>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="ServiceClass" 
                        FilterControlAltText="Filter column column" HeaderText="Service Class" 
                        UniqueName="column"  FooterText="Total">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalCustomers" 
                        HeaderText="Total Customers" SortExpression="TotalCustomers" Aggregate="Sum" AllowSorting="True" FooterText=" ">  
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                         
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Walf" 
                        DataFormatString="{0:0.0000;(0.0000);0.0000}" HeaderText="WALF" 
                        SortExpression="Walf" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " >
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                        
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalAnnualLoadWithoutUFG" HeaderText="Total Annual Load w/o UFG (dt)" 
                        SortExpression="TotalAnnualLoadWithoutUFG" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " 
                        DataFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}"
                        FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}">  
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                      
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalBaseWithoutUFG" 
                        HeaderText="Base w/o UFG (dt)" SortExpression="TotalBaseWithoutUFG" 
                        Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " 
                        DataFormatString="{0:0.0000;(0.0000);0.0000}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.0000;(0.0000);0.0000}">
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                         
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalThermalResponseWithoutUFG" 
                        HeaderText="Thermal Response w/o UFG (dt)" 
                        SortExpression="TotalThermalResponseWithoutUFG" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " 
                        DataFormatString="{0:0.00000;(0.00000);0.00000}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.00000;(0.00000);0.00000}">                                                        
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalMonthlyDeliveryQuantityWithoutUFG" 
                        HeaderText="Total Monthly Delivery Quantity w/o UFG (dt)" 
                        SortExpression="TotalMonthlyDeliveryQuantityWithoutUFG" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " 
                        DataFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}"> 
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                        
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalMonthlyDeliveryQuantityWithUFG" 
                    HeaderText="Total Monthly Delivery Quantity w/UFG (dt)" 
                    SortExpression="TotalMonthlyDeliveryQuantityWithUFG" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" " 
                    DataFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}" FooterAggregateFormatString="{0:0.0;(0.0);0.0}"> 
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />                                                       
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>  
                <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TotalDDQwithUFG" 
                    FilterControlAltText="Filter column1 column" HeaderText="Total DDQ w/UFG (dt)" 
                    SortExpression="TotalDDQwithUFG" UniqueName="column1" Aggregate="Sum" FooterText=" ">
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="left" />
                    <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="left" /> 
                </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
            </Columns>

                    <CommandItemTemplate>

                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnCsv"
                                        style="font-size:80%;"
                                        CommandName="CsvExport" 
                                        runat="server">
                            <img id="imgExportToCsv"
                                 alt="Export to CSV" 
                                 src="~/Images/reporting.gif" 
                                 runat="server" />               
                             Export to CSV
                        </asp:LinkButton>

                    </CommandItemTemplate>
                </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
```

```
</MasterTableView>
```